# How to run my JS script even browser is minimized?

Tags: jquery

I'm kinda newbie at JS. I'm writing a little JS/PHP script (wordpress) to increment a counter in DB each second (playback time tracking for a HTML mp3 player).

The main idea is that I increment my DB counter each time the 'current time' of the player change.

The code seems to work well until I switch to an other browser tab or an other app on my computer.

Any idea why the code is running only when I on the player tab ?

Nota : for debuging I put everything into function test3() and call it manually in the console.

Thanks for your help

```
function test3() {

    currentTime = clean(document.getElementsByClassName('hap-media-time-current')[0].innerHTML);
    currentTime = parseInt(currentTime, 10);
    var post_id = "5615";

    $("body").on('DOMSubtreeModified', ".hap-media-time-current", function (event) {
        currentTime = clean(document.getElementsByClassName('hap-media-time-current')[0].innerHTML);
        currentTime = parseInt(currentTime, 10);
        newTime = currentTime;

        if (oldtime == currentTime) {
            //console.log(currentTime);
            //oldtime = currentTime;
        } else {
            if (!isNaN(currentTime)) {
                console.log(currentTime);

                $.ajax({
                    url: postclick.ajax_url,
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {
                        action: 'post_playback_time',
                        post_id: post_id
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        //
                    }
                });
                oldtime = currentTime;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I expect the increment even if the browser is in background

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Events/DOMSubtreeModified see this instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: Do you have multiple `<audio>` elements or only one?

Comment: I have only one. I'm using a wordpress plugin that manage playlists, etc. But the timetracking on this plugin is not reliable. It increments only when the song is finish or when you click on next/previous. So my idea is to do time tracking, incrementing an integer in DB each second. So if you close the browser or anything else, I'm still able to have reliable time tracking

Comment: OK, mistaken, I don't have any <audio>.

Comment: Can you please insert a little piece of HTML code?

Comment: Hello,
the piece of code is to be run there : http://boredguysclub.com
the only difference is that i'll be using a new HTML5 Player plugin, so the current time class will changed from .player_mediaTime_current to .hap-media-time-current

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my suggestion: **Don't use the obsolete `DOMSubtreeModified` Event**.

Instead, inspect the DOM or try to inspect `window` and find where's your `audio` element, and track the *Listen Time* by a granularity of 1000ms by reassigning the same function to the same Element (`Event.target`) on `timeupdate` Event:

Here's an example to give you an idea that uses two Audio elements:

```js
const el_audio = document.querySelectorAll('[data-post-audio]');

const audioTimeupdate = {}; // For storing session post_id and played seconds
const listenTimeGranularity = 1000; // Do every second; or set as desired

const fn_listenTime = (ev) => {
  const el = ev.target;
  const post_id = el.getAttribute('data-post-audio');

  el.removeEventListener('timeupdate', fn_listenTime);
  setTimeout(fn_listenTime.bind(el, ev), listenTimeGranularity);

  if (el.paused) return; // Do not track time if paused
  if (!audioTimeupdate.hasOwnProperty(post_id)) {
    audioTimeupdate[post_id] = 0;
  } else {
    audioTimeupdate[post_id] += listenTimeGranularity;
  }

  // TODO: AJAX HERE
  // The post ID is: post_id
  // The total listened milliseconds are: audioTimeupdate[post_id]
  // If you increment the milliseconds on server-side, just send: listenTimeGranularity
  console.log(`
    Post ID: ${post_id}
    Listen ms: ${audioTimeupdate[post_id]}
    Increment by: ${listenTimeGranularity}
  `)
}

el_audio.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('timeupdate', fn_listenTime));
```

```html
<audio data-post-audio="5614" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/45/ACDC_-_Back_In_Black-sample.ogg" controls loop></audio>
<audio data-post-audio="5615" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/fi/c/c6/Metallica_-_Enter_Sandman_%28sample%29.ogg" controls loop></audio>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/timeupdate_event
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Unfortunatly, I don't have any <audio> in the dom.
You can see the player on my blog : http://boredguysclub.com

Comment: @EaonMagnus You're welcome. Yeah, but AFAICS you have the `window.audio` element available. Just matter or figuring out how to implement it instead of mine two...

Comment: If you type in console: `window.audio.constructor` you'll see that's some HTMLAudioELement in question, perhaps the one added by the plugin ;)

Comment: @EaonMagnus and I cannot find any `.hap-media-time-current` in your DOM...

Comment: Sorry, .hap-media-time-current is the classe for the new player for my new WP theme. On boredguysclub.com, it's .player_mediaTime_current

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert your function inside a setTimeout and not in the event:

```
setTimeout(function(){
     test3();
}, 100);
```

In this example I call setTimeout every 100ms but you can adjust for your need.

Comment: Alessio, do you think it's wise to attach over and over again an Event to the same elements? Also taking in consideration that DOMSubtreeModified is obsolete for a similar reason? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Events/DOMSubtreeModified

Comment: Absolutely not. He have to exclude the event from test3 function and call `$.ajax()` using his `if` statement. I cannot include all code now, but i will edit my answer ASAP

Comment: calling `test3()` attaches an obsolete `DOMSubtreeModified` to `body`, by re-calling `test3()` you are adding a new handler, that was my point. See the `$("body").on('DOMSubtreeModified',` ? Also, are you sure that an inactive tab listens for DOMSubtreeModified? Why not use `.one()` and than safely reattach the handler on `success`? - Or why rather not separate the AJAX into a separate function and than call that function (as you suggested) inside a `setTimeout` or rather `setInterval` that pauses on tab focus?... I'm just thinking loudly... sorry for the comment noise...

Comment: you are absolutely right. The event have to be call only once, `setTimeout` must include the real business logic including ajax

Comment: Hum, very interesting. Makes me change my paradigm. Maybe using setTimeout and the possibility to loop, i can simply use the player callbacks. I'll try this. Thank you